# Return a value from paralell stream? java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a method that uses parallelStream to run through an ArrayList of objects checking for collisions, however I'm not sure how to return a value from this sort of lambda expression inside the forEach() method. Is it impossible?

```
public static boolean isColliding(Ship moveingShip){

    Rectangle2D testRect = moveShip.getContainer(); //gets the rectangle to test

    GameManager.getArrayList().parallelStream().forEach((pS) ->
                               {if(testRect.intersects(pS.getContainer())) {//return boolean}});

    return //true or false depending on whether any collisions were detected
}
```

I don't think the forEach method has a return type, so I'm kinda stuck. Is there an alternative way of doing this besides reverting back to sequential forEach loops? The point of using parallel stream was to hopefully get through the ArrayList faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to check whether *any* value matches the predict, you can use [`anyMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

> Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided predicate. May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result. If the stream is empty then false is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.
>
> This is a short-circuiting terminal operation.

So in your case:

```
return GameManager
    .getArrayList()
    .parallelStream()
    .anyMatch(pS -> testRect.intersects(pS.getContainer()));
```

In general, I'd suggest looking down the `Stream` and `Collectors` documentation. My experience with LINQ in .NET - not exactly the same, but similar - is that data processing like this works best when you think in terms of transformations and aggregations; `forEach` is always a sort of "last resort" when you just want to take an *action* on each value, rather than getting a *result*.

Answer (score 3):

If `testRect.intersects` does nothing besides testing for collisions, you could switch to

```
GameManager.getArrayList().parallelStream().anyMatch((pS) ->
                           {if(testRect.intersects(pS.getContainer())) {//return boolean}});
```

where `anyMatch` returns `true` if the condition given matches for any `pS` in the list and exits the loop if so.